# How to get the entered card details in ngx stripe angular

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

Hi Folks i am currently working with angular ngx-stripe by following ngx-stripe document where i am getting token  when i pass card number and mm/yy cvc.but i want to get the entered card number ,mm/yy cvc. So that i can pass to backend end. Is it possible to retrieve entered details. Please help me on this.

Html

```
<h2>Create Token Example</h2>
<ngx-stripe-card
  [options]="cardOptions"
  [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions"
></ngx-stripe-card>
<button type="submit" (click)="createToken()">
  CREATE TOKEN
</button>
```

T.s

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

import { StripeService, StripeCardComponent } from 'ngx-stripe';
import {
  StripeCardElementOptions,
  StripeElementsOptions
} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(StripeCardComponent) card: StripeCardComponent;

  cardOptions: StripeCardElementOptions = {
    style: {
      base: {
        iconColor: '#666EE8',
        color: '#31325F',
        fontWeight: '300',
        fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
        fontSize: '18px',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: '#CFD7E0'
        }
      }
    }
  };

  elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
    locale: 'en'
  };

  stripeTest: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private stripeService: StripeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stripeTest = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }

  createToken(): void {
    const name = this.stripeTest.get('name').value;
    console.log(name);
    this.stripeService
      .createToken(this.card.element, { name })
      .subscribe((result) => {
        if (result.token) {
          // Use the token
          console.log(result.token.id);
        } else if (result.error) {
          // Error creating the token
          console.log(result.error.message);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: "So that i can pass to backend end." You should not be doing this. It puts you in PCI scope and means you need to do a huge audit and ongoing compliance steps. The whole point of using Stripe is to *avoid* storing real CCs (and especially CVVs!) in your backend. Store the *token*, not the card details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ceejayoz. So if i  pass that token to backend  can they validate that   and able to see  the entered card details ?

Comment: Read https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens. You can obtain details like the card type, expiration, the last four digits, etc. from one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you never get sight of the card number and as such, are not burdened with the security responsibilities.

The process is pretty much handled by Stripe via the Iframe. All you need to do is validate the payment intent at your server, which creates a secure key/token that is passed back to your client and then sent to Stripe for charging.

I'm new to this is and the process wasn't obvious initially. I think the other payment provider offer a similar process.